# How can I open the power menu in Android without pressing the power button?

Tags: automation, terminal, power-options

The power button on my Android phone is dodgy and doesn't always work. I think it's on its last legs so I want to avoid pressing it if possible to extend its lifespan!

I know nothing about coding or how Android works. But I was wondering if it is possible to send the button press event to the system using this sort of code somehow: [KeyEvent#KEYCODE_POWER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_POWER).

Is there a way I can open the power menu via the screen only? Is there something I can type into a terminal (how do you get a terminal in Android?) that would open the power menu?

Comment: I should note I'm using LineageOS and not rooted, but can root if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Settings -> Accessibility -> Set Accessibility Menu to On.
2. Press the Accessibility Menu icon, you should see among the icons, one dedicated to Power.
3. Press it to show the Power menu.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately I'm using LineageOS and the Accessibility Menu is missing, so this solution won't work for me. Is there another way?

Comment: @glauco You can install [Android Accessibility Suite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.marvin.talkback) from the Play Store (just know that it is an app by Google). There are other possibilities to show the power menu, but they all require Accessibility service.

Comment: Note that now on LineageOS 14 (240205 build on Fairphone 4) [the accessibility tab](https://i.imgur.com/jc2iMEf.png) allows enabling the [the accessibility meny](https://i.imgur.com/mTnkj0j.png) which allows emulate a power button use.